# Elixir - is there a performance penalty using it instead of plain erlang?

Tags: erlang, elixir

Elixir seems cool but I wonder about the downsides.. if any..

Are there any other potential downsides when choosing it over erlang ?

Answer (score 41):

Elixir reuses most of the compilation stack used by Erlang, so our bytecode is in general **very** close to the one you would get by compiling Erlang itself. In many cases, it just isn't the same because we include some reflection functions like `__info__/1` in the compiled module. Also, there is no conversion cost in between calling Erlang and Elixir and it will never be.

Comment: Would like to see benchmarks comparisons of any sort. Could find any

Answer (score 4):

Since elixir compiles directly to Beam bytecode, you don't incure any intermediate costs like a jitter if that's your concern.

Comment: Right but is the resulting byte code is as efficient as it could be?

Comment: I think you'll find this is localized to a) your chosen implementation and b) the constructs you choose in each language.  I think you'll find this question hard to answer as a generalization.